What to return in a preprocessing function for optimal performance
My starting point is a large polars LazyFrame.
I have written a function (def preprocessing(df:pl.Lazyframe) that has to take in a pl.LazyFrame (it can unfortunately not be a pl.Expr).
The function which does a long chain of operations on different columns of the lazyframe. Finally the output/return of the preprocessing function is only on final column that is to be appended to the starting/incoming lazyframe.
What would now be the best/optimized return type for the query planner to be integrated in the starting data frame? Should I just do a .collect().to_series(), and append it via .with_columns()? But that would require a collect and thus scarefice potential for optimization. Is there a way arround returning a series and collecting?
Unfortunately I can not share the code. However here is pseudo/mock up code:
def preprocessing(
    df: pl.LazyFrame | pl.DataFrame,
) -> pl.Series : #? tbd return type
    return (
        df.lazy()
        .with_columns(
            [
                pl.col("some_col")
                .cast(pl.Int64)
                .cast(pl.Utf8)
                .str.pad_start(5, "0")
                .alias("some_col_preprocessed"),
                pl.col("other_col")
                .cast(pl.Int64)
                .cast(pl.Utf8)
                .str.pad_start(7, "0")
                .alias("other_col_preprocessed"),
            ],
        )
# ... more steps 
        .select(
            pl.concat_str(
                [
                    pl.col("some_col_preprocessed"),
                    pl.col("other_col_preprocessed"),
                    pl.lit("42133723"),
                ],
            )
        ).collect().to_series()

starting_df = starting_df.with_columns(final_col=preprocessing(starting_df))

Downsides of returning series
I just realized a major downside of the current approach (.collect().to_series) might put me in danger if one of the steps changes the order / or had me forget the maintain_order argument.
Other Alternatives

Finding an ID column and using a join
Using the with_columns expression context and just passing in, processing and returing the complete lazyframe, without even calling .collect()


Why don't you just return the LazyFrame with the new column?

This is probably the best approach right? starting_df = preprocessing(starting_df) and then returning the complete lazyframe right?

I would think so. There's also .pipe()  so you can write starting_df.pipe(preprocessing).with_columns(other_stuff) etc.
